# DriverManagerDataSource does not have any fields, even though my spring definition is setting those fields?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, datasource

So I have a Spring bean definition as so:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/spitter/spitter" />
 <property name="username" value="sa" />
<property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

But when I look at the source code for DriverManagerDataSource, it does not have fields defined, so how can I set those fields to the values passed in through the xml if there are no fields defined in that class in the first place?

I know one of the constructors for the DriverManagerDataSource takes those variables in as parameters, but do we not need the  element if we are performing constructor-based DI?

Any help or info would be great.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Have you looked at its superclass `AbstractDriverBasedDataSource`, I suggest you take a look at the javadoc of the [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) and check what is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

`<bean>` declaration `<property>` elements work on setters not fields.

The `<property>` names you've declared are actually for properties that `DriverManagerDataSource` inherited from `AbstractDriverBasedDataSource`, its direct parent class.